# How do I re-enable atmospheres in Space Engine?

Tags: space-engine

I've accidentally turned off atmospheres in Space Engine, and I don't remember which key I've pressed. How do I re-enable atmospheres?

Comment: Do you mean Space Engineers?

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Nope, Space Engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really mean Space Engine and not [space-engineers](/questions/tagged/space-engineers), then Shift-A is toggling the display of Atmospheres. See the [User Manual](http://en.spaceengine.org/publ/user_manual/1-1-0-1#appendix3) for a complete overview of Key Bindings.

> Atmospheres on planets, moons and stars are enabled and disabled with the [Shift]+[A]. Disabling the atmosphere can lead to a substantial increase in performance on certain computers.